# AttributeError: 'Homepage' object has no attribute 'screen_manager'. Did you mean: 'ScreenManager'?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Having an issue with this button. I keep changing the reference to the screen manager as I have two, but I keep getting a similar error. Any help would be massively appreciated as I realise this is probably a stupid or obvious mistake.

I've removed one of the screens as the code was too much for stackoverflow - obviously this isn't an issue as it has no relation to the problem.

```
from kivy import Config
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationLayout

Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch')
class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList, Screen):
    pass
class NavLayout(MDNavigationLayout):
    pass
class Login(Screen):
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()
class Nav(Screen):
    Login = ObjectProperty()
    ScreenManager = ObjectProperty
    homepage = ObjectProperty()
class IconListItem(OneLineIconListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()
class Homepage(Screen):
    Login = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()
    ScreenManager = ObjectProperty

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.menu = None
        self.menu_items = None

    def submit(self):
        Popup(title='Submitted', content=Label(text='Case has been submitted and will be reviewed'),
              size_hint=(0.5, 0.5)).open()
        sm = self.ids.screen_manager
        scr = sm.get_screen('Create Case')
        for child in scr.children:
            if isinstance(child, TextInput):
                child.text = ''

    def dropdown(self):
        self.menu_items = [
            {
                "viewclass": "IconListItem",
                "icon": "git",
                "font_size": 25,
                "text": f"Nice {i}",
                "height": dp(56),
                "on_release": lambda x=f"Item {i}": self.set_item(x),
            } for i in range(5)
        ]

        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.ids.drop_item,
            items=self.menu_items,
            position="center",
            width_mult=4,
        )
        self.menu.open()

    def set_item(self, text_item):
        self.ids.drop_item.set_item(text_item)
        self.menu.dismiss()


class AddNewCustomer(Screen):
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class AddNewStaff(Screen):
    pass
class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    Login = ObjectProperty()
    homepage = ObjectProperty()
class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        # Window.maximize()
        # self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        # self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "900"
        login = Builder.load_file("login.kv")
        return login


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

```
ScreenManager:
    Login:
    Homepage:
    AddNewCustomer:
    Nav:
    DrawerList:
<Login>:
    name: "login"
    font_name: "Century"
    MDCard:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 700, 800
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        elevation: 10
        padding: 25
        spacing: 25
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Image:
            source: 'images/asteria.png'
            size: 100, 200

        MDLabel:
            id: login
            font_size: 40
            font_name: "Century"
            halign: 'center'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            padding_y: 15

        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: user
            hint_text: "username"
            font_name: "Century"
            icon_right: "account"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 200
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: password
            hint_text: "password"
            font_name: "Century"
            icon_right: "eye-off"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 200
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            password: True

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "LOGIN"
            font_size: 12
            font_name: "Century"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "homepage"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "CLEAR"
            font_size: 12
            font_name: "Century"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            on_press: app.clear()


        Widget:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50


<Nav>:
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "[font=Century]Add New Customer[/font]"

                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "addNewCustomer"
                    root.screen_manager.transition.direction = "right"


            OneLineListItem:
                text: "[font=Century]Add New Staff[/font]"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "addNewStaff"

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "[font=Century]Case List[/font]"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "caseList"


            OneLineListItem:
                text: "[font=Century]Create Case[/font]"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.screen_manager.current = "Create Case"


            OneLineListItem:
                text: "[font=Century]Create Case Version 2.0[/font]"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.screen_manager.current = "Create Case Version 2.0"


            OneLineListItem:
                text: "[font=Century]Create Case Version 3.0[/font]"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.screen_manager.current = "Create Case Version 3.0"



            OneLineListItem:
                text: "[font=Century]Log Out[/font]"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")

                    root.manager.current = "login"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"



<Homepage>:
    name: "homepage"
    Screen:

        MDNavigationLayout:
            ScreenManager:
                id: screen_manager
                Screen:
                    name: "Homepage"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Welcome Home"
                        font_name: "Century"
                        halign: "center"


                Screen:
                    name: "addNewCustomer"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Add New customer"
                        font_name: "Century"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "addNewStaff"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Add New Staff"
                        font_name: "Century"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "caseList"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case List"
                        font_name: "Century"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "casePool"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Pool"
                        font_name: "Century"
                        halign: "center"

            
                Screen:
                    name: "Create Case Version 2.0"


                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Title"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.875, "center_x": 0.180}



                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: CaseTitle
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        icon_right: "Case Title"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: True
                        height: 4000
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.863, "center_x": 0.220}



                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Customer"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.791, "center_x": 0.180}




                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Customer
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        icon_right: "Customer"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.779, "center_x": 0.220}


                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Customer Forename"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.707, "center_x": 0.180}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Customer Forename
                        hint_text: "Info here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        icon_right: "Customer"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 14
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.687, "center_x": 0.220}

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Customer Surname"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.623, "center_x": 0.180}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Customer Surname
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        icon_right: "Customer"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 14
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.603, "center_x": 0.220}

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Alternative email"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.803, "center_x": 0.360}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Alternative Email
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.779, "center_x": 0.400}

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Alternative Phone"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.707, "center_x": 0.360}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Alternative phone
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.687, "center_x": 0.400}



                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Source"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.623, "center_x": 0.360}

                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Case Source
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.603, "center_x": 0.400}




                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Priority"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.523, "center_x": 0.360}

                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Case Priority
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.503, "center_x": 0.400}




                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Category"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.423, "center_x": 0.360}

                    MDDropDownItem:
                        id: drop_item
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": .403, "center_x":  0.400}
                        text: 'filler text in here'
                        width: 275
                        on_release: root.dropdown()



                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Possible Cases"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.887 , "center_x": 0.360}



                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: PossibleCases
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        icon_right: "Case Title"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.863, "center_x": 0.400}



                    ThreeLineListItem:
                        text: "Knowledge Helper"
                        font_size: 15
                        secondary_text: "This is a multi-line label where you can"
                        tertiary_text: "fit more text than usual"
                        width: 275
                        size_hint_x: None
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.915, "center_x": 0.645}



                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Description"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.883, "center_x": 0.745}



                    MDTextField:
                        id: Case Description
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        icon_right: "Case Title"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        multiline: True
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.863, "center_x": 0.790}

                    MDRoundFlatButton:
                        text: "Submit"
                        font_size: 60

                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.400,"center_x": 0.700}
                        on_release: root.submit()







                Screen:
                    name: "Create Case Version 3.0"


                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Title"
                        font_name: "Century"
                        font_size: 30
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.875, "center_x": 0.180}



                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: CaseTitle
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        font_name: "Century"
                        icon_right: "Case Title"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: True
                        height: 4000
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 30
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.860, "center_x": 0.180}



                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Customer"
                        font_name: "Century"
                        font_size: 30
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.788, "center_x": 0.180}




                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Customer
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        font_name: "Century"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        icon_right: "Customer"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 30
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.773, "center_x": 0.180}


                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Customer Forename"
                        font_size: 30
                        font_name: "Century"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 300
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.701, "center_x": 0.180}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Customer Forename
                        hint_text: "Info here"
                        font_name: "Century"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        icon_right: "Customer"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 30
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.687, "center_x": 0.180}

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Customer Surname"
                        font_size: 30
                        font_name: "Century"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 300
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.615, "center_x": 0.180}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Customer Surname
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        font_name: "Century"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        icon_right: "Customer"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 30
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.601, "center_x": 0.180}

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Alternative Email"
                        font_size: 30
                        font_name: "Century"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        width: 275
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.875, "center_x": 0.380}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Alternative Email
                        hint_text: "ewan@jccomtech.com"
                        font_name: "Century"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 25
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.860, "center_x": 0.380}

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Alternative Phone"
                        font_size: 30
                        font_name: "Century"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275

                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.788, "center_x": 0.380}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Alternative phone
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        font_name: "Century"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 25
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.773, "center_x": 0.380}



                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Source"
                        font_size: 30
                        font_name: "Century"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        width: 275
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.701, "center_x": 0.380}

                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Case Source
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        font_name: "Century"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 25
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.687, "center_x": 0.380}




                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Priority"
                        font_size: 30
                        font_name: "Century"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        width: 275
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.615, "center_x": 0.380}

                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Case Priority
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        font_name: "Century"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 25
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.595, "center_x": 0.380}




                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Category"
                        font_size: 30
                        size_hint_x: None
                        font_name: "Century"
                        multiline: False
                        width: 275
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.423, "center_x": 0.380}

                    MDDropDownItem:
                        id: drop_item
                        font_size: 25
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": .423, "center_x":  0.450}



                        font_name: "Century"

                        width: 275
                        on_release: root.dropdown()







                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Knowledge Helper"
                        font_size: 30
                        font_name: "Century"
                        width: 275
                        multiline: False
                        size_hint_x: None
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.875, "center_x": 0.580}

                    MDTextField:
                        id: Knowledge Helper
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        font_name: "Century"
                        icon_right: "Case Title"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        multiline: True
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.863, "center_x": 0.580}






                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Description"
                        font_size: 30
                        font_name: "Century"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.883, "center_x": 0.780}



                    MDTextField:
                        id: Case Description
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        font_name: "Century"
                        icon_right: "Case Title"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        multiline: True
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.863, "center_x": 0.780}


                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Possible Cases"
                        font_size: 30
                        font_name: "Century"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.351 , "center_x": 0.380}



                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: PossibleCases
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        font_name: "Century"
                        icon_right: "Case Title"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 25
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.337, "center_x": 0.380}

                    MDRoundFlatButton:
                        text: "Submit"
                        font_size: 60
                        font_name: "Century"

                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.400,"center_x": 0.700}
                        on_release: root.submit()




        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDToolbar:
                title: '[font=Century]Navigation[/font]'
                height:'100dp'

                font_name: "Century"

                left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('open')]]

                canvas:
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: (((self.parent.size[0])/2)+760,self.pos[1])
                        size: (200, 100)


                        source: 'images/asteria3.png'

                Button:
                    screen_manager: screen_manager
                    manager: root.manager
                    text:'Homepage'
                    font_name: 'Century'
                    pos: (((self.parent.size[0])/2)+500,self.pos[1])
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: (100, 100)
                    on_release: root.ScreenManager.current = "homepage"

            Widget:


        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            Nav:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
                manager: root.manager
```

Comment: How do I reproduce that error? I can run your code but cannot get that error.

Comment: Hi, there's a homepage button on the top bar. It should throw that error when clicking that on any page.

Comment: The `HomePage` button was off screen. Looking at it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems:

- Too many things named `ScreenManager`. There is a class named `ScreenManager`, and anytime you do `ScreenManager = ...` you are in for trouble. Change `ScreenManager` to something else. Also change your defined class from `class ScreenManager(ScreenManager)` to some other name, like `class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager)`.
- In your python code you have `ScreenManager = ObjectProperty` in at least two places. One problem with that is that you must use `someName = ObjectProperty()` (Note the `()`) in order to create an `ObjectProperty`. And see previous problem.
- In your `kv` code, your `Homepage` button tries to set the `current` screen to `homepage`. It should be `Homepage` to match the `name` set in the `kv`. Assuming that you are trying to get to the screen that has the `Welcome Home` Label.
- In your `kv` the code, you need to add a line to set the value of the `ObjectProperty` that holds the reference to the `ScreenManager`. Kivy will not allow you to define a property named `ScreenManager` due to the conflict with the class named `ScreenManager`.

Try changing:

```
<Homepage>:
    name: "homepage"
    Screen:

        MDNavigationLayout:
            ScreenManager:
                id: screen_manager
                Screen:
                    name: "Homepage"
```

to:

```
<Homepage>:
    name: "homepage"
    scrmgr: screen_manager  # added reference to ScreenManager
    Screen:

        MDNavigationLayout:
            ScreenManager:
                id: screen_manager
                Screen:
                    name: "Homepage"
```

And in your python code:

```
class Homepage(Screen):
    Login = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()
    scrmgr = ObjectProperty()  # changed from ScreenManager
```

And the `HomePage` Button can then be:

```
                on_release:
                    root.scrmgr.current = "Homepage"
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much - It makes sense now why I have always been running into issues with the screen manager as I clearly didn't see that was a poor choice of name. I did originally have the name correctly as "Homepage", but I think when I was frustrated I must've changed it. Do you have any tips on making it so the scaling for various screens fit? It looks ok on my desktop screen but on anything smaller it looks awful. Thanks Again.